# Get the array's item count after passing the string value in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable that has a string value such as "A1,A2,A3". Then I want to put these values into an array and get the count of items in that array. I tried to use the split() method but it gives me ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined***

following is my code
movieData.seats have the following data as a string [A1,A2,A3..]

```
componentDidMount() {
        let movieInfo = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
        console.log(movieInfo.movieid) 
        this.setState(movieInfo)
        console.log(movieInfo.seats)          
        movieData = movieInfo 
        
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
          };
          fetch(`http://sandbox-api.com/v1/seat/prices?venue_id=90&movie_id=3232&showtime_id=2130&movie_date=2021-08-02`, requestOptions)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then((seatPrice) => {
                console.log(seatPrice.data.ticketPrices.priceList)
                this.setState({ 
                    seatPrice: seatPrice.data.ticketPrices.priceList,
                    dataLoaded: true,
                      
                 })
                 const filteredODCData = seatPrice.data.ticketPrices.priceList.filter(type => type.seatType.includes("ODC"));
                 const adultPrice = filteredODCData[0].adultPrice;
                 const childPrice= filteredODCData[0].childPrice;
                 
                 
                 const filteredBoxData = seatPrice.data.ticketPrices.priceList.filter(type => type.seatType.includes("Box Seats - Ground Floor"));
                 const adultBoxPrice = filteredBoxData[0].adultPrice;
                 
                 const advanceCommision = seatPrice.data.ticketPrices.advancedCommission;

                 console.log(adultPrice)
                 console.log(childPrice)
                 console.log(adultBoxPrice)
                 console.log(advanceCommision)
                 
                 this.setState({
                    seatPrice: seatPrice.data.ticketPrices.priceList,
                    adultPrice: adultPrice,
                    childPrice: childPrice,
                    adultBoxPrice: adultBoxPrice,
                    advanceCommision: advanceCommision,
                    dataLoaded: true, 
                 })

              }).catch(console.log);


    }


    render () {
        const {seatPrice, dataLoaded} =this.state;
        const adultPrice = this.state.adultPrice;
        const childPrice= this.state.childPrice;
        const adultBoxPrice= this.state.adultBoxPrice;
        const advanceCommision = this.state.advanceCommision ;

        console.log(adultPrice)
        console.log(movieData.seats)
        var count = (movieData.seats);
        console.log(count)
```

I'm new to react and would like to have answered with some explanation
following is my URL parameters

http://localhost:3000/#/bookingSummary?movieid=3232&movieName=Mortal%20Kombat&venueId=90&showtimeId=2130&movieDate=showtdates.date&seats=A6,5,5,A6,A6,5

[image: error]

Comment: The moviedata.seats [A1,A2,A3..] looks like array to me. So you can get length as count.length

Comment: I have updated. please check.It's a string that A1,A2,A3 these data get

Comment: Are you able to `console` the output of `count`, from the error it seems your count variable is not defined?

Comment: is your string varibale like that  movieData.seats = 'A1,A2,A3';

Comment: @MhammedTalhaouy yes just like this = A6,5,5,A6,A6,5

Comment: @RyanFonseka Problem is not in `.split(",")`. Just read the error, It says `(count)` in `(count).split(",")` is `undefined` i.e `count` is `undefined` and you cannot invoke any function on `undefined`

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: @RyanFonseka What does `console.log(count)` print on console?

Comment: this is what i get A6,5,5,A6,A6,5

Comment: If you're getting `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` then for sure `count` is `undefined`. Debug your code and see where it went wrong

Comment: @decpk i will update the full code please check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var string = "A1,A2,A3";

console.log(string.split(',').length)
```

Here, `split` will convert your string into array and array has `length` property, which will return the length of array.

Comment: this works but when i replace string with count variable it gives me error. I get the movieData.seats value from URL parameters I want the count of movieData.seats. let me know if it is possible

Comment: One more thing which you can do here is, use this block of code.
new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search).get({{your_query_param_name}}).split(',').length.

Let me know if it helps. I will add it in above answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
let movieData = 'A6,5,5,A6,A6,5';
let movieDataLength = movieData.split(',').length;
console.log(movieDataLength);
```

Comment: this works but when i replace string with count variable it gives me error. I get the movieData.seats value from URL parameters I want the count of movieData.seats. let me know if it is possible

Comment: did you display count in console ```console.log(count)```

Answer (score 1):

```
let count = movieData.seats;
let result= count.split(",");
console.log(result.length)
```